# For $A$ accretive, $R_{\lambda} := (I + \lambda A)^{-1} \in \mathcal L(\mathcal H)$ and metric map

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal H$ be a Hilbert space and $A \in \mathcal L(\mathcal H)$ be accretive, i.e. $\langle -Av + Aw, v-w \rangle \le 0$ for all $v,w \in \mathcal{H}$. I want to show that then $R_{\lambda} := (I + \lambda A)^{-1} \in \mathcal L(\mathcal H)$ exists for every $\lambda \ge 0$ and also that it is a metric map, i.e. $\|R_{\lambda}v - R_{\lambda}w\| \le \|v-w\|$ for all $v,w \in \mathcal{H}$.

My approach: For $\lambda \neq 0$, I can try to find a solution for $(I + \lambda A)v = f$ with the recursion formula

$\frac {v^{n+1} - v^{n}}{\tau} + (I + \lambda A)v^n = f $ for arbitrary $v^0$ and some suitable $\tau > 0$. How to continue?

[Different solutions are also welcomed]

Comment: What is meant by $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$?

Comment: The set of bounded linear maps $\mathcal H\to\mathcal H$.

Comment: It's not true, you are essentially looking at the resolvent of a monotone operator and that is not always linear. We can show it is a function (i.e. single valued) though.

Comment: What is the connection to inverse problems?

Comment: Actually I retract my previous statement, I didn't realize that you assumed $A\in\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another word for metric map is nonexpansive operator. To see that $R_{\lambda A}$ is nonexpansive we first define the Cayley operator,

$$C_{\lambda A} := 2R_{\lambda A} - I$$

where $I$ is the identity. We will show that the Cayley operator is nonexpansive and the nonexpansiveness of $R_{\lambda A}$ will follow since it is the average of $C_{\lambda A}$ and the identity (i.e. $R_{\lambda A} = \frac{1}{2}(C_{\lambda A}+I)$)

Let $(x,u)\in gra(R_{\lambda A})$ and $(y,v)\in gra(R_{\lambda A})$, then we have

\begin{equation}
|C_{\lambda A}(x) - C_{\lambda A}(y)|_2^2 =|2R_{\lambda A}(x)-x - 2R_{\lambda A}(y)+y|_2^2 = |2(u-v)+y-x|_2^2\\
= 4|u-v|_2^2 - 4\langle u-v, x-y\rangle +|x-y|_2^2 \leq |x-y|_2^2
\end{equation}

Thus $C_{\lambda A}$ is nonexpansive and we are done.

Comment: Please tell me why these two equalities/inequailities hold: $|2(u-v)+x-y|_2^2\\
= 4|u-v|_2^2 - 4\langle u-v, x-y\rangle +|x-y|_2^2 \leq |x-y|_2^2$.

Comment: Write the norm as an inner product and expand everything using bilinearity of the inner product

Comment: Actually there was a sign error but it is fixed now the. The main idea is the same nonetheless, use the definition of the Cayley operator and then expand everything as an inner product using bilinearity. Once you have expanded everything you can get rid of the inner product because it is negative by accretivity of $A$.

edit: I suggest you look at this powerpoint: https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/monotone_slides.pdf a monotone operator is an accretive operator in some sense.